# SKLabelNode creates black line and not showing text on iPhone4

Tags: sprite-kit, iphone-4, sklabelnode

I am loading different texts into a SKLabeNode it works fine on iPhone5, simulator, etc... but on iPhone4 I sometimes just get a black line, instead of the text.

It is weird that always the same texts are generating the failure, but I cannot figure out what is happening.

The code is:

```
ButtonText=@"";

    ButtonLabel=[SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Marker Felt"];
    ButtonLabel.fontSize=46;
    ButtonLabel.text=ButtonText;
    ButtonLabel.position=CGPointMake(0, 0);
    ButtonLabel.verticalAlignmentMode=SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter;
    ButtonLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode=SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter;
    ButtonLabel.colorBlendFactor=1.0f;
```

When I am changing the text, simply using the

```
ButtonLabel.text=NewString;
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: What's the exact text of "NewString"? Have you checked that it is non-nil and an actual NSString (CFString) object? Try: NSLog(@"%@ %@", NewString, NSStringFromClass([NewString class]);

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. This is what is returned with NSLog line. "Hány olimpiai bajnokságot nyert Kemény Dénes a vízilabdázóival? __NSCFString". The same is on iPhone5 or simulator, but on iPhone I cannot see the text, just a kind of black placeholder in the size of the rendered text line.

Comment: The software is a quiz game and downloading questions from a web service, with the answers. Most of the questions are ok and visible on iPhone 4 too, but always the same questions are generating this stupid effect. Actually I am changing the game from cocos2d to sprite kit due to compatibility issues as I would like to port the game to OSX as well later.

Comment: I just add the NewString.length to the NSLog. All NSStrings equal or longer than 54 characters generating the issue on iPhone4 can this be a kind of limitation somewhere_

Comment: I have changed the font type from Marker Felt to Verdana. Now it failes when the text length is 44 characters or above. This must be a bug in Sprite Kit.

Comment: I have checked it in the simulator, switching to Retina 3.5" and it fails too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have filed a bug report on this bug to Apple. After few weeks they replied and requested to check the issue with the updated IOS. It worked better and accepted longer texts. Later they fully solved the problem.