# SKLabelNode Creating Black Rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973340/sklabelnode-creates-black-line-and-not-showing-text-on-iphone4), but it did not have a definite solution to the issue, nor is it the exact same. I am trying to simply add a SKLabelNode with some text. I have never had issues but for some reason this is happening:
[image: Black bar is the SKLabelNode]
Here is the code I am using to generate the node:

```
var announceLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Baskerville")
announceLabel.text = "ERROR LOADING ANNOUNCEMENT"
announceLabel.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
announceLabel.fontSize = 200
announceLabel.setScale(twitterButton.frame.height / announceLabel.frame.height)
announceLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
self.addChild(announceLabel)
```

I am testing this on my iPhone 6, and I have never had this happen while creating a label node. I have attempted different fonts, positions, and scales with no effect. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil That black bar should be text

Comment: weird i ve never had that before... but fontSize = 200??? isn't it too big?

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil ha I tested that right when you commented that. Yes it turns out the font size was too big. It is just strange as I have used font size 200 before with no issues.

Comment: glad that worked , maybe you used for UILabel element before, happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested some more and I found the answer. The font size was too big and I guess caused a bug with SpriteKit. I changed the font size to 50 and it worked fine (I have used font size 200 on other label nodes and never had an issue):

```
var announceLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Baskerville")
announceLabel.text = "ERROR LOADING ANNOUNCEMENT"
announceLabel.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
announceLabel.fontSize = 50
announceLabel.setScale(twitterButton.frame.height / announceLabel.frame.height)
announceLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
self.addChild(announceLabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but it's just on the iPhone 6+ simulator & I think the actual device also.  Works fine on 6, 6, 4s, iPad 2 & iPad air.

What I had to do to make the text show is to decrease the font size.  In my case I was using a font size of 64 (Hobo Std) & had to reduce it to 56.  BUT, I found out the length of the line was part of the reason.  If the line was about 45 characters or less it displayed at size 64, but when it was about 50 characters long it became a black rectangle at size 64 but worked fine at size 56.  So seems to be a combination of font size & number of characters.

This must be a bug, but is still in Xcode 6.4

Answer (score 0):

Two and a half years later, and I'm running into the same problem. It seems like when the width of the SKLableNode exceeds a certain size, it just shows as a black rectangle. I did a quick binary search and found the bad size is between 2038 and 2054, so I'm going to go out on a limb here and say the cutoff is at 2048. I guess it's a bug in SpriteKit? I don't see any documentation on it...

Work arounds:

1. Halve your font size and double your scale. This is what I'm doing for now, i.e. my fontSize went from 64 to 32, and setScale(2). Downside is that the font isn't as high quality. Also this only increases your limit to effective 4096 points. So a really long label still won't work.
2. Cut your text up into chunks that produce SKLabelNodes no larger than 2048. Might be painful to get text layout just right this way.

Answer (score 0):

I've come from the future to bring you some closure. 
In 2018 we still have the same problem with big SKLabelNodes.

Now a lot of Apple devices uses @3x assets, and it became pretty clear that Simulator sucks on reproduce large @3x images, exhibiting them as a black retangular/squared shape. To be clear: this bug is restricted to high res images on simulated devices.

It also affects SKLabelNodes because the way it works. The SKLabelNode renders the text as an high res image before displaying it. It's make sense to render it as a high res image because text readability needs detail, also to allow scaling.

So if choosing a font big enough got you through the same trouble, it's safe to say that the simulator @3x rendering process needs some debugging.

---

## TL;TR

- The reports of the problem in this thread and others indicates that's a SIMULATOR bug only affecting images bigger then @2x displayed by simulated devices.
- The SKLabelNode generates a high resolution image for exhibition, so
  there is the problem.
- If you're sure of what you're doing, it will look fine on real devices.